# arrows-and-boxes plugin jquery

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I am trying to implement arrows-and-boxes plugin to implement some diagram.  If use static content it works but if i use dynamic content through Jquery its rendering as text but not as diagram.

```
       <html>
        <head>
     <script src="js/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.wz_jsgraphics.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="arrowsandboxes.js"></script>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="arrowsandboxes.css">       
    <script language="javascript">
somefunction.gettestChainChain('<%=test%>');

</script>
    </head>
   <body>
   <pre class="arrows-and-boxes" id="testChain">
      ---my content with apprear here
   </pre>

     </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Place your scripts *after* the tags in the body.

Comment: Tried...but no use. I am using FancyBox to display this as popup.

Answer (score 0):

you can do whatever you want like you can set an empty `<div>` with `id=node` then append box code as html on this div

```
$("#node").html('<pre id="testChain" class="arrows-and-boxes"> (User) > (Admin) </pre>')
```

after finishing just call this line inside script tag

```
<script>
$("#testChain").arrows_and_boxes();
<script>
```